# Arrange by "Kind" doesn't separate various types

Tags: finder, high-sierra

When using the **Arrange by** function in the Finder I see most guides and various questions online regarding it, that it "should" separate images, music, movies, etc. into different sections. While it definitely used to do that for me; recently it does not.

I still have Folders, Applications, Documents, PDFs & Developer, but everything else is just listed under "other".

OS 10.13.6

Any advice is appreciated to get this working as intended.

[image: Screenshot of a Finder window with the Options window]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you're seeing in the finder window, and the settings window showing what you've chosen.

Comment: Updated with a screenshot. Assuming you mean view options, by settings window?